# C# Windows Form User Control Not Recognized by Calling Form

Tags: c#, winforms, user-controls, delegates, eventhandler

I'm writing a simple user control with two buttons:  Save and Cancel.  I think that it thinks there are no subscribers because it's always null where I indicated in the code.  Please help.

Here is the code for the user control:

```
public partial class SaveCancelButtons : UserControl
{
    public delegate void SaveClickedHandler();
    public delegate void CancelClickedHandler();

    public SaveCancelButtons()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    public event SaveClickedHandler SaveClicked;
    public event CancelClickedHandler CancelClicked;

    protected virtual void OnSaveClicked()
    {
        if (SaveClicked != null)         <<<<-----  ALWAYS NULL
        {
            SaveClicked();  // Notify Subscribers
        }
    }
    protected virtual void OnCancelClicked()
    {
        if (CancelClicked != null)        <<<<-----  ALWAYS NULL
        { 
            CancelClicked();  // Notify Subscribers
        }
    }
    private void btnSave_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        OnSaveClicked();

    }
    public void btnCancel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        OnCancelClicked();
    }

  }
```

Here is how I am calling it:

```
public partial class TestForm : Form
{
    public TestForm()
    {
        // declare and subscribe to the user control
        SaveCancelButtons scb = new SaveCancelButtons();
        scb.SaveClicked += UC_SaveClicked;
        scb.CancelClicked += UC_CancelClicked;
        this.Controls.Add(scb);

        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void UC_SaveClicked()
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Save!");
    }
    private void UC_CancelClicked()
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Cancel");
    }
}
```

Comment: Hmmm, I think it's missing something. Check out this little tutorial, see if it helps. They wrap the call in EventHandler, maybe try that. http://csharp-station.com/Tutorial/CSharp/Lesson14

Comment: Thank you for that link!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to mix delegates and events here. If all you want is the methods in form to be called when you click on user control buttons, declare events in the user control and register callback functions in the form. I made changes to your code. This code will show dialogues on clicking buttons in the user control

```
   public partial class SaveCancelButtons : UserControl
    {
         public delegate void SaveClickedHandler();
          public delegate void CancelClickedHandler();
        public SaveCancelButtons()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

        }

        public event EventHandler SaveClicked;
        public event EventHandler CancelClicked;

        protected virtual void OnSaveClicked()
        {
            EventHandler handler = SaveClicked;
            if (SaveClicked != null)         //
            {
                handler(this,new EventArgs());  // Notify Subscribers
            }
        }
        protected virtual void OnCancelClicked()
        {
            EventHandler handler = CancelClicked;
            if (CancelClicked != null)       // <<<< 
            {
                handler(this,new EventArgs());  // Notify Subscribers
            }
        }

        private void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            OnSaveClicked();
        }

        private void btnCancel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            OnCancelClicked();
        }
    }
```

your form changes

```
public partial class TestForm : Form
{
    public TestForm()
    {
            // declare and subscribe to the user control
            SaveCancelButtons scb = new SaveCancelButtons();
            scb.SaveClicked += Scb_SaveClicked; ;
            scb.CancelClicked += Scb_CancelClicked; ;
            this.Controls.Add(scb);

            InitializeComponent();
    }

        private void Scb_CancelClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Cancel");
        }

        private void Scb_SaveClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Save!");
        }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much.  I appreciate your help in seeing where I was going wrong.